# Simple neon optimization in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

In my Android application, I use a bunch of open source libraries such as libyuv, libvpx, libcrypto, libssl, etc. Some of them come with Android.mk. For others, I hand-crafted Android.mk.

The code is built only for arm for now. Here is my Application.mk:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti
```

I am looking for way to generate binaries that are optimized for neon. Browsing the net, I found the following setting that someone is using in his Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -march=armv7
```

I wonder if I simply put this setting in Application.mk, will it automatically get applied across all the libraries?

A step before each library is built is the following:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
```

Is it better to include LOCAL_CFLAGS directive after this line (instead of including it in Application.mk)?

Finally, why doesn't ndk-build automatically optimize for neon when it sees armabi in Application.mk? Regards.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't automatically optimize for neon because not all ARM devices have neon.

Adding those cflags will only be applied if building from source.  If you have a .so that you're just moving across it will not change that file at all.

Comment: agree, after all, needs to rewrite your code in neon instead.

Comment: Obviously, I am building all the sources:-). Not sure what you mean by need to write your code in neon. Cannot imagine one person rewriting the source code for all the open-source libraries that I mentioned.

Comment: He meant the compiler needs to rewrite the .so using neon opcodes (which wouldn't be understood by a non-neon processor).